# How does Docker Desktop pick version of Linux to run?

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, docker-desktop

I'm running Docker Desktop on Windows. I have the following settings:

[image]

running wsl command confirms Ubuntu as the default distro

[image]

Does this mean when I spin up a container, it will run on Ubuntu?

When I spin up a container, I see that it runs Debian.

```
# cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
#
```

How is it that Debian is picked over Ubuntu?

**Update**:

So, the container running the Linux version is specified in Dockerfile.  In Dockerfile, the base image is set to be `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0`  I am guessing that in that image, Microsoft specifies the flavor of Linux. Although [there are images for all OS versions](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-sdk?tab=description)  I am not sure how it picks Debian.

Comment: You're seeing whatever is in the `/etc/os-release` file in the container, which is a separate filesystem from the host system or the WSL environment.  The Linux kernel is shared between all containers and the host or Linux VM, but most of the filesystem is not.

Comment: @DavidMaze So, the container running the Linux version is specified in Dockerfile?  In Dockerfile, the base image is set to be `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0`  I am guessing that in that image, Microsoft specifies the flavor of Linux. Although [there are images for all OS versions](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-sdk?tab=description)  I am not sure how it picks Debian.

Comment: @dev.e.loper you are spot on! Microsoft has published multiple version of the same image that have different base images (and so run on different distros). For example `6.0-bullseye-slim` runs on Debian 11, `6.0-alpine3.17` runs on Alpine 3.17, `6.0-alpine` runs on Alpine 3.16, `6.0-jammy` runs on Ubuntu 22.04 and `6.0-focal` runs on Ubuntu 20.04. The `6.0` tag happens to be an alias of the `6.0-bullseye-slim` tag so it runs Debian 11. Take a look at [this](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-sdk?tab=description) unde _Full Tag Listing_ for more info

Comment: @MatteoZanoni "The 6.0 tag happens to be an alias of the 6.0-bullseye-slim tag"  <- where can I see this alias mapping?

Answer (score 0):

The "Ubuntu" selection in the Docker Desktop Resources Settings means that you *can* run `docker` and related commands *inside* that distribution.  If you were to unselect the Ubuntu distribution, you would still be able to run `docker` from PowerShell and CMD, but it would not work inside Ubuntu.

If you have multiple WSL distributions, it's useful to specify the one that you want to be active for Docker Desktop, since *all* selected distributions will run *constantly* as long as Docker Desktop is running.

---

As mentioned in the comments, the distribution (if there is one) for the *container* is determined by the container's `Dockerfile` (which may be upstream).  However, keep in mind that a container doesn't even need a distribution.  It can be as simple as a single, statically-linked binary.

As for the example that you gave, if you pull the "default" (`:latest`), then you'll see in the "Full Tag Listing" on [the container's page](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-sdk?tab=description) that the tag `latest` is a synonym for some of the other Bullseye tags:

- `7.0.101-bullseye-slim-amd64`, `7.0-bullseye-slim-amd64`, `7.0.101-bullseye-slim`, `7.0-bullseye-slim`, `7.0.101`, `7.0`, `latest`

At some point, `latest` will be reassigned to a newer (a) .NET SDK, and (b) Debian distribution (although less frequently, obviously).